# Does offsetof require pointer derefence?

Tags: c++, c, macros, undefined-behavior, offsetof

I am wondering whether a simple macro `offset_of_` requires a pointer dereference of not. For example, a `C++` (means that this code will be compiled using a C++ compiler) struct which is declared with packed attribute

```
struct A {
  int x;
  int y;
} __attribute__(packed);
```

Suppose that `sizeof(int) == 4` in this case, to calculate the offset of `y` inside `A`, I wrote a simple macro:

```
#define offset_of_y (ptrdiff_t)(&(((A*)0)->y))
```

Can we be sure that the value of this macro is always `4`? Is there any pointer dereference from `0` (which may be a UB) when the macro is invoked?

Many thanks for any response.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176835/discussion-on-question-by-ta-thanh-dinh-does-offsetof-require-pointer-derefence).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing something through a null pointer is UB, period.

<sup>(Unless the context is unevaluated, but in this case it IS evaluated.)</sup>

You probably want [`offsetof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof).

---

In practice your code probably *could* work, buf formally it's undefined.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176830/discussion-on-answer-by-holyblackcat-does-offsetof-require-pointer-derefence).